# How to hide warnings in Laravel mix

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

When I run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` I get a un-scrollable amount of warnings in my terminal. How can I hide these warnings so they will not be printed to the terminal output? I am using Laravel 7.30.4, Node v15.0.1 and npm 7.0.3.

[image: un-scrollable amount of warnings]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel Mix will display a system notification for each compilation.
That way, you can quickly see if you have any errors that need addressing.
However, in certain circumstances, this is undesirable (such as compiling on your production server). If this happens to be the case, they can be disabled from your `webpack.mix.js` file.

```
mix.disableNotifications();
```

Maybe you only want to be notified if there are any errors? That is possible too, by only disabling the success notifications. Please note that this is intended to be used via the `watch` command. The first compilation always displays a success notification. Only subsequent success notifications are disabled.

```
mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
```

and you can add this following to your mix configuration base on this [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/).

```
mix.webpackConfig({
     stats: {
         warnings: false,
     }
 });
```

Comment: This is straight copy paste from the [Official documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/os-notifications). This answers something else. Not my particular question.

Comment: Yes, I straight copied from this Document, Because I thought it would help you. Describe your question clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Farid! Even though your answer didn't help, the update you did to it and the URL of the webpack documentation gave me some insights. You know, referring documentations always helps ;) I will look further as I am allocated time for it and will mention any updates here. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I tried the updated code and it worked for me and didn't show warnings. I hope the document is useful to you